# "Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.5"" while starting MySQL

Tags: mysql, upstart

I have a mysql that has been working fine but now will not start.  All I've been able to accomplish is using

```
sudo start mysql
```

which generates the following error:

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.5" (uid=1000 pid=1678 comm="start mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

I've tried googling sections of it, but it seems this is basically a useless error.  Anyway I can get more information about what is going on?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 43):

The problem is this:

```
uid=1000
```

That bit means that the user that contacted Upstart to perform the start action has the uid 1000 (not root, root is 0). That uid is usually assigned to the first non-system user. Something must be severely wrong with your usage of sudo, or sudo itself, because the command is not properly escalating to root.

You can see the same error with this command, for comparison (note the absence of sudo):

```
start --system mysql
```

Comment: so do `sudo start mysql` got it

Comment: The original question appears was using `sudo`. This did help me with the same error though, but I wasn't using sudo in the first place.

Answer (score 13):

The recommended way to start services is to use the `service` command:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: IMO, `start` is a shorthand for `service $1 start`, so it should be the same.

Comment: @Braiam `start` is actually `initctl` (a symlink), which does `initctl start ` when called as `start`.

Comment: How is `initctl start` different than `service ... start`?

Comment: My server crashed while restoring a DB and then this problem raised it head. The suggested solution worked to get it running again but I need to do this manually each time I start the server.